# Image not found on <img src={{ asset(...) }}

Tags: laravel, laravel-excel, laravel-storage

This is my blade Looks like :

```
<img src="{{ asset('/assets/img/logo.png') }}"  alt="logo" width="60px" height="60px">
```

And here's my folder structure

[image: img file]

When i try to view the blade, its fine. But when i try to Export as PDF with Laravel-Excel, the error coming up

> http://localhost:8000/assets/img/logo.png not found!

I already change asset() to url() and without laravel function but the error still coming, any suggestions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved

```php
<img src="{{ public_path('assets/img/logo.png') }}" ... />
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
{{ asset('assets/img/logo.png') }}
```

without the initial "/"
https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/helpers#method-asset

Answer (score 0):

Have you try this

```
<img src="/assets/img/logo.png"  alt="logo" width="60px" height="60px" />
OR
<img src="{{URL::asset('/assets/img/logo.png')}}"  alt="logo" width="60px" height="60px" />
```

Please try these!